# Visualizing image cube

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 3D Matrix of 256*256*30. Each cell contains a 16-bit integer intensity value.
How can I visualize this cube in Matlab ?

Comment: The proper question is how you want it to be visualized. And then you should ask how to do it in Matlab.

Comment: I want to see it as a cube. I would like to be able to explore the cube along an arbitrary axis of my choice, if this is not too much :) What other options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you basically have is a 3D heatmap. You can visualize this in a straightforward way, or you can transform it into a 3D contour plot that would give you a better idea of higher or lower density regions.

This isn't a cakewalk, but here's are visualizations that people did with Mathematica for similar data: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/3d-heatmap-density-plot. I think the transformation for contour plots is especially useful given our visual limitations to two dimensions on an screen. You can rotate the contour plot around to look at it from any angle.

As an alternative, since one of the dimensions is much smaller than the other two, I would visualize it as 30 slices, each a 2-dimensional heatmap. Similar approaches are taken for viewing medical imaging, for example tomography data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_computed_tomography

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free 3D Slicer medical image visualization application to do this (http://www.slicer.org). Its MatlabBridge extension allows calling Matlab functions and visualize the results in various ways in both 2D and 3D (http://www.slicer.org/slicerWiki/index.php/Documentation/Nightly/Extensions/MatlabBridge).